# Makefile error No targets specified and no makefile found

Tags: makefile

here is my makefile:

```
sandbox:sandbox.o
   ld -o sandbox sandbox.o
sandbox.o:sandbox.asm
   nasm -f elf -g -F stabs sandbox.asm
```

I put a tab character for the command line, but when i try to make the file, it gives me the error:
No targets specified and no makefile found

I am using Jeff Duntemann's book and that makefile error is driving me nuts because I can't progress in my study right now!!!

Comment: What is the name of your makefile and how exactly do you try to run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be you are messed up "*a tab character for the (make) command line*" with "*tab character in make recipe command line, i.e. in Makefile itself*". The first has no sense for make. The latter is required since the basic syntax of Makefile is the following:

```
<target>: [ <dependency > ]*
   [ <TAB> <command> <endl> ]+
```

Thus, you should either use **sandbox** as a target

```
> make sandbox
```

or add to your Makefile the following default target:

```
all: sandbox
```

and build with only make:

```
> make
```